# Where is the accent symbol in Musescore?

Tags: musescore

I'm creating some scales to work with. My music teacher has asked me accent the first note in each measure. I'm looking for the symbol within Musescore that represents accent.

https://musescore.com/csmu/c-major-scale-from-middle-thumbs-001

Is it Sforato or Fade out or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick answer - select the note, press Shift-V.

I discovered this by calling up the Handbook from the Help menu in MuseScore, and entering 'accent' into the Search box.

I think we can agree that an accent is unlikely to be represented by a fade-out!  Though I agree that the handbook could have more helpfully said 'Accent (sforzato)'  than 'Sforzato (accent)'.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the PDF manual. I thought it might be 'Sforzato' because it matched the accent symbol within https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_musical_symbols but so did 'Fade out'. Fade out didn't make sense to me, Sforzato didn't make sense to me. I used Sforzato but no change was made in the sound output ... hence my question.